# HBase & single node (Pseudodistribution) installation

Tags: hbase

1. in the book of Lars George I read that you should not define a master as a regionserver. If that is true what do I put into the "regionservers" file in conf folder for a Pseudodistribution? there is already a localhost there. should i delete it too and leave it empty?
2. do I need a zookeeper for this Pseudodistribution?

I already installed a 3 mashines clusters running but i am having problems with the single node onw.

regards,

Comment: You mention you have a 3 node cluster so its a distributed cluster. pseudo distribution is when you have all running hadoop procesess on one node. the steps to configure are mentioned here hbase.apache.org/book.html#distributed

Comment: yes i know the difference ofcourse. I am trying to build a test system in "single node". that's another story from the cluster i made running already and i am having above problems there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can leave the localhost there in the regionservers file.
2. Have the following configuration entry in your hbase-site.xml
         
          hbase.zookeeper.quorum
          hostname
3. Ensure you the following entry in your hbase-env.sh
   export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true

You would need zookeeper to run in a pseudo distributed mode also.